# Android SMS receiving and handling

Tags: android, sms, handler, android-broadcastreceiver

I know that it is possible to handle incoming sms on android and I think even me as a beginner can do that. But my question is: Will the app also run when the device is locked? I am working on an application that sends an email with the text and sender to a specific email address when the device received a SMS. But it also has to work when the device locked itself after a few minutes? Whats the best way to do that or is it already working by using the onRecieve method?
Thanks for any kinda help and please be kind I am quite new to programming :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complicated...

As soon as an app is paused (that means : not displayed on the screen), it could be destroyed by the Android system to preserve battery or reduce CPU / RAM usage.
So : no, you have no guarantees the app will still be alive.

You can set a `BroadcastReceiver` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` and create a `BroadcastReceiver` class in your app. The `onReceive()` method will be called and the code you set in your class will be executed. Even if the app is not running at the moment the SMS is received.

But there's another issue : Deep Sleeping. To preserve battery, Android will turn off any battery-intensive systems when the device is not used for many hours. Battery-intensive systems includes : Wi-fi and Data. SMS is excluded from this list (but some constructors may include an option to disable SMS receptions when in Deep Sleeping, in this case, you have no option, just warn the user to not disable SMS receptions in Deep sleeping), gracefully.

That means implementing the `onReceive()` method will not be sufficient. You will need to wake up the device to enable Wifi and Data, allowing you to send an email.

So, to avoid this problem, extends a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`. This is like a "normal" broadcast receiver, but it will wake up the device, and let it sleep again when the code is fully executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all that information!! Helped me a lot, I really appreciate that! I need this app for my own business only so I can put the settings on the phone however I needed. So I won't disable SMS reception in Deep sleeping. So Did I get that right that I should you the WakefulBroadcastReceiver in order to make this work properly?

Comment: That's correct. Just extends `WakefulBroadcastReceiver ` and put your code inside the `onReceive()` method.